# Get file object from audio-tag (Html5)

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have already a working audio-tag with a src in form of a link.

Now, for analyzing the music and visualize this, i need a File-object.
File-objects are basicly from the users disk, there's a possibility to load a blob via ajax/xhr.

The solution with a blob would mean, i download every track 2x from the server, what's nonsense. So i thinked, it's maybe possible to extract the file-object from the audio-tag that is downloading anyway.

I've searched in api's and via google, but found only the opposite (load files to a audio-tag), but that's done already..

edit: found the buffered-value here, but how to convert this to a file-object?

no clue..https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_buffered.asp :editEnd

Would be genious if there's a solution. Thanks in advance!

edit2: found a solution that works for me here: https://www.cssscript.com/audio-visualizer-with-html5-audio-element/

Answer (score 0):

found a solution that works for me here: https://www.cssscript.com/audio-visualizer-with-html5-audio-element/

here it converts the audio-src not to a file, but to the same object i need for audio-analysing.